# Run tornado web app in my own computer as server

Tags: python, tornado

I have a tornado web app and I configure it to run it locally as follow

my-sourse.py

```
app.listen(7000)
```

then

```
$ python my-sourse.py
```

I want to use my own pc for test so I want to configure it to run on my ip address

I reviewed the [doc](http://tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/overview.html#running-tornado-in-production)  and it explains how to configure on production enviroment as  nginx but I need the simplest way.

With django app I use the command

```
python manage.py runserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:7000
```

How do I do it with [tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy, sorry for silly question but I'm really newbie with tornado.

just change:

```
app.listen(7000)
```

for:

```
app.listen(7000, 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx')
```

This question could help others newbies so I'll leave it here.